# HTML Table Export to CSV wont export more then 50 rows

Tags: javascript, html

I have got an export script that takes my HTML table and exports it as a csv.

The only problem is it seems to limit itself to just 50 rows.

I'm afraid there is too much to paste on here but if you look in my head you can see the included files :)

http://php-playground.co.cc/testdir/metaex.php

Comment: We cant fix the script if we can't see it... there must be some code in there that is limiting it. Just post the relevant bits if it is too long

Comment: oh... and your link is blocked by my anti-virus ;)

Comment: So, you translate all the TDs into a new form and POST that data that in turn generates a CSV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, the page wasn't UTF 8 so it was cutting off whenever it saw a character it didn't like!